# Has Xcode removed scm icons?

Tags: xcode, svn, xcode4

We use a 1.7 svn server.  But I have the 1.7 command-line installed.  And I have soft-linked the svn apps in the Xcode bundle to the opt versions.

I get green lights for my repository in the organizer window and I can update.

I also can filter source code status in the project navigator.  But the SCM modified icon doesn't appear for the modified files.

Is this a change in Xcode 4.4 or a bug?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a change in Xcode 4.4. SCM icons appear next to files in the project navigator for me for both git and local Subversion repositories. Something else is wrong, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: It was my ignorance.  You have to switch on the SCM icons. <smack forehead>